# It seems like a box-shadow of the div remains as 'overlay' when I resize the div

Tags: css, sass

I've made a chapter overview page with 'tiles' that can be clicked on, and when a user clicks the tile is enlarged and the others are hidden. The content of the tile changes from the chapter name to a paragraph overview. The 'orginal' tile's box-shadow seems to remain and lay on top of the one of the enlarged tile. I can't seem to get rid of this effect and don't know what's causing it.

I've tried to remove the shadow completely on all the tiles, but the effect stays. When I remove all the tiles from the page except for one, the effect remains. The code be found on https://github.com/renesteeman/Informatica-Methode-Xampp/tree/master/design%20V2. Only the first tile is 'filled out'and the jquery file only hides the tiles when one is clicked as well as mark the clicked tile with class "active". The lines also move when you zoom in.

[In this image the red box points out where the (white) shadow is, it's quite subtle with the current colors, but it still bugs me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LyBm.png)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that not all of the code on Github is needed to demonstrate the issue. So, can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: From the looks of the other "tiles" in your comp, you have a box shadow as inset in front (the one that's not transitioning) and one as a regular shadow behind the tile. Is the former declared on a psuedo element like ::before or perhaps a background image that is not being modified with the transition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be with the `box-shadow` being set to the `.chapter-tiles .tile:before` in **main.sass** line number 162.

```
.tile:before
    width: 15em
    height: 15em
    content: ""
    position: absolute
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 15px rgba(250,250,250,0.1)
    filter: blur(10px)
```

This section of code seems to be inessential. You may either remove the whole block or can clear the `box-shadow` when the `active` class is added to the `.tile`.

```
.tile.active:before
    box-shadow: none
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That was perfect! Thank you! It seems like I pasted it there by accident, these are the kind of mistakes that you overlook when you think you know your code.

Comment: Glad that I could help. You may upvote and/or mark the answer as correct so that it would help other users. Thank you.